# How do I access all children and change the text one by one using for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this HTML code:

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
for($olindex=0; $olindex<3; $olindex++){
    $("#id1").children("#id3").eq($olindex).text(result2[$olindex]);
}
```

Now things are not working: There's nothing wrong with `result2[$olindex]` but still the text is not displayed in each element with `id3`. Maybe I've written wrong DOM code. How can I correct or change it to make it work?

Comment: You want to insert text in every Div element with a id of id3?

Comment: IDs must be unique!!!

Comment: Yes. I want to insert in every div.

Answer (score 3):

Your selectors are incorrect. If you want to select elements by ID, use `#`:

```js
var result2 = [0,1,2];
for(var $olindex=0; $olindex<3; $olindex++) {
  $("#id1").children("#id3").eq($olindex).text(result2[$olindex]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
</div>
```

That said, IDs must be unique. Use another approach, e.g. classes.

Answer (score 2):

You've used several `div` elements with the same `ID`. `ID` should be unique per `element`, which is causing your issue.

You're better off using `classes` for your divs:

```
<div id="id1">
    <div class="id2"></div><br>
    <div class="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="id2"></div><br>
    <div class="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="id2"></div><br>
    <div class="id3"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

You can then use your JQuery Selector with a class instead:

```
$("#id1").children(".id3")
```

Comment: Yes, IDs should be unique. Classes can be used for several elements.

Comment: The first jQuery selector should be $("#id1") - with a hash, not a dot

Comment: IDs not being unique does not cause the problem, CSS will select them all. The problem is that the selectors are completely incorrect.

Comment: I just did that for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
'<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="id1">
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="id2"></div><br>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <br>
</div>

<script>

for($olindex=0; $olindex<3; $olindex++){                     
    $("#id1").children("#id3").eq($olindex).text(result2[$olindex]);

}

</script>'
```

If you are using IDs you need to use "#", not ".". "." is for classes.
Also, I don't recommend using the same ID for multiple elements.